# C confusing pointer arithmetic

Tags: c, pointers

I have confusion in C pointer arithmetics.
I learned that when I add or subtract pointer address, It add or subtracts with multiple of Its data type.
For example:

```
int *p =90;
p+=1;
printf("%d",p);
```

returns 94 since 90+1*4 =94.

however, following code returns strange result.

```
void set_next_block_size(long long int * current, long long int size){
    *(current+1+size/8)=size;
}
```

I guessed the value in ( ) would be current+8+size since long long int type takes 8bytes but It is actually calculated as current+1+size/8 ..

what is long?

Comment: Although you have declared p as a pointer, 90 is not an address, you use pointers to point to a memory location not an absolute value.  In your example p will be incremented and the value at the next location will be random.

Comment: __(1)__ What is `Int`??

Comment: __(2)__ `int *p =90;` is purely implementation defined behaviour. IIRC, it's a constraint violation, too.

Comment: It was just simple example for testing pointer arithmetic. I got address of 'current' using malloc

Comment: For any pointer (or array) `p` and index `i`, the expression `*(p + i)` is exactly equal to `p[i]`. That means the expression `*(current+1+size/8)=size` is exactly equal to `current[1 + size / 8] = size`.

Comment: __(3)__ `printf("%d",p);` is also wrong, it must be `printf("%p",(void *)p); `

Comment: Considering (1), (2) and (3)....Please start referring to a good C book/ tutorial.

Comment: (1)I'm learning Scala programming these days in my university and therefore I mistakenly typed Int instead int.. and (2) was just to check arithmetic of pointer. I know it does not really referencing valid memory address.

Comment: @JiseopHan "I know it does not really referencing valid memory address" --> C code that attempts even pointer math on invalid pointer values is _undefined behavior_ (UB)  - even without a reference attempt.  The presence of UB in code reduces greatly its value as a learning effort.

Comment: Thank you for your advise. Now I notice undefined behavior of C and I will try to write sample code more precisely next time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
void set_next_block_size(long long int * current, long long int size){
    *(current+1+size/8)=size;
}
```

> I guessed the value in ( ) would be current+8+size since long long int type takes 8bytes but It is actually calculated as current+1+size/8 ..

You guessed wrong. And from the first snippet you seem to know the rules for pointer arithmetics: `+1` actually means "move the pointer address by 1 element of the type pointed to, which is 4 bytes".

Now you want to move to the next element and you want to use the size instead of the number. Why should it be different now?

It still works the same as before.

If you add `+8` you will add `8*sizeof(long long int)` bytes. This would change the address by `64+size` bytes which is not what you seem to want.
Instead you only want to add 1 element + `size`. That's why it is `+1` and not `+8`

Comment: You add +1 to move by 1 int element. That's fine. But you add +8 to move 1 long long int element. Why should that work totally different? If you want to move by 1 element, you add +1. If your guess were correct, why didn't you add +4 in the first snippet?